# Application ID different form Bundle ID?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, code-signing

I have an application with two targets (for two versions of the app, free and paid), but when trying to submit, I realized I would have to create another distribution profile so the application could have a different ID. Now, after creating siad profile, I get this error:

```
Code Sign error: Provisioning profile 'YourApp Free Distribution' specifies the Application Identifier 'com.yourCopmpany.YourAppFree' which doesnt match the current setting 'com.yourCompany.YourApp'.
```

I looked around for solutions, but nothing seemed to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. I had to change the product name. It seems that it was automatically generating a Bundle ID and ignoring the one in the info.plist.

Comment: Do you mean the name of the build target?  Where was the product name that you were changing?

Comment: In the target settings there's a field called "Product Name"

Answer (score 3):

Check these three things:

1. Create a separate `Info.plist` file for your paid and free apps, each with its own unique app id.
2. Double click on each target under `Groups & Files` to see the unique build settings for each.  Search for `Info.plist` under the `Packaging` section.  Set the `Info.plist` field for the paid and free targets to their correct individual `Info.plist` files.
3. While you're in the target build settings for each project, make sure your provisioning profiles are unique for each build target, NOT for the project as a whole.

This should get you up and running, if not, please post more detail about your situation.

Comment: No good. I can't even select the correct distribution certificate.