# Trouble with code signing ad-hoc release of second target

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ad-hoc-distribution

I have a project with two targets. I just can't code sign the newer target. I intend to make an ad-hoc release. Even though I put everywhere the correct provision file, xcode keeps looking at the provisions for the older target. This is the error I get:

"Provisioning profile 'some-name' specifies the Application Identifier 'identifier1' which doesn't match the current setting 'identifier2"

Comment: Check the target you are trying to build. You might building the other target

Comment: nope, the target is chosen correctly.

Comment: Do you have separate info.plist files for the targets? Check the bundle identifiers in the plist files

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4653408/1263701) can help you.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue last night. (Seems to be a bug with X-code when there has been more than one bundle identifier with the same app?)

I "solved" it by setting code signing identity in `Build Settings` to `Don't Code Sign` for all targets, quitting X-code then restarting and re-assigning the targets you want:

[image]

After re-assigning, it seemed to pick up the correct provisioning profile.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was hiding in 'edit schemes'. The 'Archive' section was not set on Ad-hoc, but on Release. So I put it on Ad-hoc. Now it works.